# Array Remove middle terms

Tags: java, arrays

For my AP Computer Science AB class, we are required to make a program that is able to remove the middle term(s) from an array and my code constently returns an out of place 0 how can I fix this?
For example: [6, 2, 10, 2, 0] returns [6, 0, 2, 0] when the desired output is [6, 2, 2, 0]

```
if (arrayE.length % 2 == 0) {
  int[] newArray = new int[arrayE.length - 2];

  for (int i = 0; i < (arrayE.length / 2) - 1; i++) {
    newArray[i] = arrayE[i];
  }
  for (int i = (arrayE.length / 2); i < newArray.length; i++) {
    newArray[i] = arrayE[i + 2];
  }
  arrayE = newArray;
} else if (arrayE.length % 2 != 0) {
  int[] newArray = new int[arrayE.length - 1];

  for (int i = 0; i < (arrayE.length / 2) - 1; i++) {
    newArray[i] = arrayE[i];
  }
  for (int i = (arrayE.length / 2); i < newArray.length; i++) {
    newArray[i] = arrayE[i + 1];
  }
  arrayE = newArray;
}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: If you can use it look at [Arrays.copyOfRange](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-int:A-int-int-)

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza `System.arraycopy` is a better choice, since you can copy into an existing array.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you take arrayE.length /2 the int it returns would be 2. You are then subtracting  - 1 for two. Effectively you have 2 - 1. so your array in this case is basically

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
  System.out.println("ran");
}
```

That only prints it out. The error is that you are never actually modifying the second index. Remove the -1.

This code should work fine.

```java
if (arrayE.length%2!=0)
        {
            int[] newArray = new int[arrayE.length - 1];

            boolean pastMidPoint = false;
            for(int i = 0; i < arrayE.length; i++){
                if(i == (arrayE.length / 2)) {
                    pastMidPoint = true;
                    continue;
                }
                if(!pastMidPoint)
                    newArray[i] = arrayE[i];
                if(pastMidPoint)
                    newArray[i - 1] = arrayE[i];
            }
            arrayE = newArray;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you just want to remove the middle term from the array, you can try the following approach. In the case of an odd numbered size array:

```
public static int[] getOddLengthArray(int arrayE[]) {
     int size = arrayE.length;
     int indexToRemove = ((size+1)/2)-1;
     int[] newArray = new int[size-1];
     int newArrayIndex = 0;
     for(int oldArrayIndex=0;oldArrayIndex<size-1; oldArrayIndex++) {
         if(oldArrayIndex!=indexToRemove) {
             newArray[newArrayIndex] = arrayE[oldArrayIndex];
             newArrayIndex++;
         }
     }
     return newArray;
}
```

Try and figure out the even numbered one for yourself!

Comment: indexToRemove could be just size/2, there is no need for that +/-1 magic.

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code is this expression: **(arrayE.length / 2) - 1**
For the "odd" case you need to use the same boundary **arrayE.length / 2** in the both loops.